# how to find the code in java script which is modifying the data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Assume there is a json data stored in a variable and multiple functions were modifying the data.Is there any way in javascript or from dev tool to find which code has modified the data.

```js
var employeeDetails = {
  name: "John",
  age: 22
}

function updateEmployeeDetails1() {
  employeeDetails.age = employeeDetails.age + 1;
  console.log("In employeeDetails1()", employeeDetails)
}

function updateEmployeeDetails2() {
  employeeDetails.name = employeeDetails.name + "Papa";
  console.log("employeeDetails2()", employeeDetails);
}

function sayHello() {
  console.log("HELLO");
}

updateEmployeeDetails1();
updateEmployeeDetails2();
sayHello();
```

Is there any way to check which method has modified the employeeDetails object and in specific an attriubte ("lets say name") ?

Comment: For the future, please inlcude all necessary  code in the question, not just as a link

Comment: using debagger of webbrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution would be to set breakpoints in the function and step through the code to get a better gasp of what is happening.

[image]

A different approach would be to override the setter and getter function of the object and dynamically break the code when ever this variable is changed. This has the advantage of you not needing to find all the places the variable is changed from.

https://jsfiddle.net/8t3czxkb/2/

```
var employeeDetails = {
  age: 22,
  name: "John"
};

//Debug object properties

debugObject = (obj) => {
  for (const prop of Object.keys(obj)) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
      get: function() {
        console.log("get " + prop);
        debugger; 
        return this["_" + prop];
      },
      set: function(value) {
        this["_" + prop] = value;
        debugger;
        console.log("set " + prop);

      }
    })
  }
}

debugObject(employeeDetails);

employeeDetails.name = "John";

function updateEmployeeDetails1() {
  employeeDetails.age = employeeDetails.age + 1;
  console.log("In employeeDetails1()", employeeDetails);
}

function updateEmployeeDetails2() {
  employeeDetails.name = employeeDetails.name + "Papa";
  console.log("employeeDetails2()", employeeDetails);
}

updateEmployeeDetails1();
updateEmployeeDetails2();
```

Comment: 1. Using devtools: If its a large application and the data is being referred in multiple functions across multiple files, it would be difficult to put break point in multiple places.                                2. Using accessor methods:  A property cant have a value and accessor method on it. Could you elaborate more on the usage considering the code mentioned in the question

Comment: What do you mean by a property can't have a value and accessor method on it?
The following example works just fine for me. Every time the name value is set the debugger shows the call stack and thus revealing were the modification happened.
var employeeDetails = { 
  age: 22,
  set name(value) {this._name = value; debugger},
  get name() {return this._name},
  name: "John"
}

Comment: I tried using getters and setters, neither the debugger nor the console logs in the accessor methods were triggered.  https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-monad-7109k?file=/src/index.js

Comment: You have the option to either add them to the object after initialization or add the properties of the object. The following is working for me. You have to open the dev console in order for the debugger to show: https://jsfiddle.net/8t3czxkb/2/